# How to make the pop() function of a stack, defined by linked nodes, return its string value properly?

Tags: c, string, function, linked-list, stack

**Edit: I had some change to my code. The edited code will be put right down here. Thanks for your suggestions!**

```
typedef struct node{
    struct node* next;
    char value[];
}node;

typedef struct stack{
    node* top;
}stack;

node* init_node(char c[])
{
    node* p = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node) + strlen(c) + 1);
    if (p == NULL) return NULL;
    strcpy(p->value, c); p->next = NULL;
    return p;
}

stack* init_stack()
{
    stack* s = (stack*)malloc(sizeof(stack));
    if (s == NULL) return NULL;
    s->top = NULL;
    return s;
}

int push(stack* *s, char c[])
{
    node* p = init_node(c);
    if (p == NULL) return -1;
    p->next = (*s)->top;
    (*s)->top = p;
    return 0;
}

bool isEmpty(stack* s)
{
    return (s->top == NULL);
}

char* pop(stack* *s)
{
    if (!isEmpty(*s))
    {
        node* p = (*s)->top;
        char* res = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
        strcpy(res, p->value);
        (*s)->top = p->next;
        free(p);
        return res;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I put the 'res' pointer into the `pop()` function, and I allocate its memory when just initializing it. This really works!

-----***-----

I'm working on an exercise which requires me to use a stack built on linked nodes, and each node must have its value being a string, instead of number as usual.

However, I can't find out a way to return the string value with the function `pop()`. In other words, it seems to be an undefined behavior, having the return code of -1073741819 (it's accessing unallocated memory, if I remember correctly)

This is my code for the functions to work with stack:

```
typedef struct node{
    struct node* next;
    char value[];
}node;

typedef struct stack{
    node* top;
}stack;

char* res;

node* init_node(char c[])
{
    node* p = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node) + strlen(c) + 1);
    if (p == NULL) return NULL;
    strcpy(p->value, c); p->next = NULL;
    return p;
}

stack* init_stack()
{
    stack* s = (stack*)malloc(sizeof(stack));
    if (s == NULL) return NULL;
    s->top = NULL;
    return s;
}

int push(stack* *s, char c[])
{
    node* p = init_node(c);
    if (p == NULL) return -1;
    p->next = (*s)->top;
    (*s)->top = p;
    return 0;
}

bool isEmpty(stack* s)
{
    return (s->top == NULL);
}

const char* pop(stack* *s)
{
    if (!isEmpty(*s))
    {
        node* p = (*s)->top;
        strcpy(res, p->value);
        (*s)->top = p->next;
        free(p);
        return res;
    }
}
```

All other functions work well except the `pop()` one. I used to meet problems with memory allocation for flexible string member in a struct, but this time I don't think it comes from that.

Then how should I edit my code?

Comment: What does `res` point to when this line is executed? `strcpy(res, p->value);`

Comment: Don't use global variables. And instead of returning a pointer, let the caller pass in a pointer (and a size) that you use as the destination for the string.

Comment: Note: `pop` doesn't return anything if `s` is empty.

Comment: `pop` should be identical as for an `int` except for the type.

Comment: Tip: Most of `init_node` can be replaced by `strdup`.

Comment: Make sure ```node* p = (*s)->top``` in function ```pop``` does not point to ```NULL```.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh my `if` line with the condition of `!isEmpty()` is enough, right?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I'm a bit confused at that part too. According to what I know, after the line `free(p)`, that `res` pointer would point to `NULL`, as the destination assigned to it earlier got removed. However I haven't found out the true way to work with it yet, so I just keep that line to remind myself of the idea, not as an actual working line.

Comment: @KurakamiGenya, the first comment here was not about what `res` will *become*, but what it is when you first access it with `strcpy(res, p->value)`. It is actually a hint that something is wrong. (`strcpy` will write to the memory that `res` points to -- what is it pointing to??)

Comment: @KurakamiGenya No. It does check if node list is not empty. What I am saying is that make sure the top of your list that would be popped, is not NULL.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh thanks for your reminder, but that's what I get from the `isEmpty()` function. In other words, they're the same :>

Comment: @trincot thanks for that idea. I moved  the `res` pointer into the `pop()` function and initialized its memory with a `malloc()`, and it seems working properly now. I forgot initializing even after so many times working with the node pointers above, such a shame.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm working on an exercise which requires me to use a stack built on linked nodes, and each node must have its value being a string, instead of number as usual

A stack is just a (possibly empty) *container* of nodes. And each node contains or points to a unit of something, a data record.

> Then how should I edit my code?

IMHO the code as posted has much to be changed. But in order to work `pop` must be changed and I will show a minimum change, plus code for testing and the results

```
const char* pop(stack** s)
{
    if (!isEmpty(*s))
    {
        node* p = (*s)->top;
        strcpy(res, p->value);
        (*s)->top = p->next;
        free(p);
        return res;
    }
}
```

- There is no reason to return `const char*`: the data is being extracted from the stack and the caller can do whatever wanted with the data.
- `s` is an input value: there is no point in passing the adress of a pointer to a stack. Prefer `char* pop(Stack* )`
- `res` is a problem: WTF is `res`? There is no reason to rely on an external pointer

Consider

```
char* pop(stack** s)
{
    if (s == NULL) return NULL;
    if ((*s) == NULL) return NULL;
    if (isEmpty(*s)) return NULL;
    node* p   = (*s)->top;
    char* res = malloc(1 + strlen(p->value));
    strcpy(res, p->value);
    (*s)->top = p->next;
    free(p);
    return res;
}
```

### editing the code

Consider the usual header, code and test files, as here

#### `v0.h`

```
#pragma once
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node
{
    struct node* next;
    char         value[];
} node;

typedef struct stack
{
    node* top;
} stack;

node*  init_node(char[]);
stack* init_stack();
int    push(stack**, char[]);
bool   isEmpty(stack*);
char*  pop(stack**);
```

#### `v0.c`

```
#include "v0.h"

node* init_node(char c[])
{
    node* p = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node) + strlen(c) + 1);
    if (p == NULL) return NULL;
    strcpy(p->value, c);
    p->next = NULL;
    return p;
}

stack* init_stack()
{
    stack* s = (stack*)malloc(sizeof(stack));
    if (s == NULL) return NULL;
    s->top = NULL;
    return s;
}

int push(stack** s, char c[])
{
    node* p = init_node(c);
    if (p == NULL) return -1;
    p->next   = (*s)->top;
    (*s)->top = p;
    return 0;
}

bool isEmpty(stack* s) { return (s->top == NULL); }

char* pop(stack** s)
{
    if (s == NULL) return NULL;
    if ((*s) == NULL) return NULL;
    if (isEmpty(*s)) return NULL;
    node* p   = (*s)->top;
    char* res = malloc(1 + strlen(p->value));
    strcpy(res, p->value);
    (*s)->top = p->next;
    free(p);
    return res;
}
```

#### `main0.c` to test the thing

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "v0.h"

char* factory();

int main(void)
{
    char*  el  = NULL;
    stack* one = init_stack();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i += 1)
    {
        el      = factory();
        int res = push(&one, el);
        printf("push() returned %d for '%s'\n", res, el);
        free(el);
        if (res != 0) return -1;
    }
    char* p = NULL;
    printf("\n\n    Now pop() until error\n\n");
    while ((p = pop(&one)) != NULL)
        printf("pop() returned '%s'\n", p);
    return 0;
}

char* factory()
{
    // Element 1234567
    static number = 1;
    char* value   = malloc(16);
    if (value == NULL) return NULL;
    sprintf(value, "Element %7d", number);
    ++number;
    (number == 9999999) ? 1 : number + 1;
    return value;
}
```

#### output

```
push() returned 0 for 'Element       1'
push() returned 0 for 'Element       2'
push() returned 0 for 'Element       3'
push() returned 0 for 'Element       4'
push() returned 0 for 'Element       5'
push() returned 0 for 'Element       6'
push() returned 0 for 'Element       7'
push() returned 0 for 'Element       8'


    Now pop() until error

pop() returned 'Element       8'
pop() returned 'Element       7'
pop() returned 'Element       6'
pop() returned 'Element       5'
pop() returned 'Element       4'
pop() returned 'Element       3'
pop() returned 'Element       2'
pop() returned 'Element       1'
```

Comment: My fault, I didn't edit the original post after it has been solved. The problem is just that I hadn't allocate the memory for the `res` pointer before using it. But anyways, your code gives me a new look on this, especially the header file's code :>